# How to make square container with size depending on height in %?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I'm developing on WordPress/Elementor and I need to create a footer made of single squares with content in each of. The final products is meant to
[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCvdT.png)

As a solution, I thought about making the height depend on the width of the sqaures which is specified in VW, and converting it to px for the width height.

How can I realize this idea (in JS maybe?) or us there an even easier way to solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for JavaScript, this layout can be achieved with css:

```css
footer .footer-row {
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100vw / 3);
}

footer .footer-row .footer-column {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

footer .footer-row:first-of-type .footer-column {
    background-color: #c0c193;
}

footer .footer-row:first-of-type .footer-column:first-of-type {
    background-color: #c5c4c4;
}

footer .footer-row:last-of-type .footer-column:first-of-type {
    background-color: #93acad;
}

footer .footer-row:last-of-type .footer-column:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #d5cdbf;
}

footer .footer-row:last-of-type .footer-column:last-of-type {
    background-color: #c4c4c3;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-row">
                <div class="footer-column"></div>
                <div class="footer-column"></div>
                <div class="footer-column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-row">
                <div class="footer-column"></div>
                <div class="footer-column"></div>
                <div class="footer-column"></div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```